# Spark plug and coil only one is bad for 2012 Honda odyssey

Tags: honda, sparkplugs, ignition-coil, odyssey

I am trying to find out if I have one spark plug (#3 to be exact) as well as the coil can I change just the one or is it bad for the engine to do so?

Comment: They're fairly cheap online, you could just replace them both...or one at a time...

Comment: Has this vehicle had the Honda engine misfire problem repaired in the past?

Answer (score 7):

If you find the coil is bad, change just the coil. You can do this without issue.

If you find the spark plug is bad, change all of them. When spark plugs start going bad, it is a good bet others will probably follow in short order. It will also ensure all spark plugs are of the same age and useage. This will better help in equalizing power production across the cylinders. If things are tight, you could get away with changing just one, but really, it's not something I'd do.

Answer (score 3):

1. Try swapping the #3 coil with another cylinder and see if the problem follows.
2. Try swapping the #3 spark plug with another cylinder and see if the problem follows.

That should let you know where the problem lies.